# SQL SELECT with GROUP BY and show all values into a column

Tags: sql, mysql

So I have user table in my MySQL

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Matt |
| 3 | Matt |

What I want to achieve is showing all the names without duplicates and store it as an array in PHP

My query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user GROUP BY name)";
```

Result

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 3 | Matt |

With the above query, I managed to remove the duplicates by sorting the newest id. But the result im looking for is this

| all_name |
| --- |
| John, Matt |

Is there anyway to get the above result? I'm new to MySQL hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ', ') AS names
FROM `user`
```